# how do I set the width to 100% of the current router outlet?

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

My website has a menubar which is in the main component html and inside this html is also the app-selector of another component:

**MainComponent.html**

```
<div style="height:200px">This is my Menubar</div>
<app-test></app-test>
```

I would like to display 3 boxes in my testComponent.html.

I am using flexLayout: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout

```
 <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-between none" style="height: 100%">
   <div style="background-color: red">
    T1
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: blue">
    T2
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: yellow; height: 200px">
    T3
  </div>
 </div>
```

The problem is that because there is a menubar, i get a scrolling behaviour but I just want the last box to end at my screen bottom. See here: http://prntscr.com/nhwcbp

How can I achieve this?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/flex-layout-angular-material-xssepa

Comment: Would you mind creating a demo on stackblitz.com ? It would be more easy to understand

Comment: yes, here you go: https://stackblitz.com/edit/flex-layout-angular-material-u3spdk

Comment: Check out my answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. put below style in `style.css`:

`html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; }`

2. Remove `height: 100vh` and make use of flexbox

```
<div fxLayout="column" style="height:100%">
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center">
        <mat-card fxFlex="50">
            <div fxLayout="row">
                <div fxFlex="30" class="action-blurb">This is a blurb.</div>
                <div fxFlex="30" class="action-blurb" fxFlexOffset="5">This is a blurb.</div>
                <div fxFlex="30" class="action-blurb" fxFlexOffset="5">This is a blurb.</div>
            </div>
        </mat-card>
    </div>
    <div fxFlex="">
        <app-test></app-test>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope this should do the trick as per [this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/flex-layout-angular-material-ddugeb?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: thank you. it seems that the problem is somewhere else. It does not work when I use the angular material sidenav: https://stackblitz.com/edit/flex-layout-angular-material-xssepa

Comment: @M4V3N : You need to do `<mat-sidenav-content fxLayout="column">` . Here is the demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/flex-layout-angular-material-n5huup?file=app/app.component.html .

Comment: I see. Thank you. What would I need to change if I want the middle area to take all the remaining space? if I give it the "fxFill" attribute it gives me a scrolling behaviour again.

Comment: @M4V3N With middle area are you mean `T2` ?

Comment: yes, exactly. Because my bottom area should act as a "sticky footer". and the middle area is the actualy content.

Comment: @M4V3N: add `<div style="background-color: blue;height: 100%;">` to `T2` as per demo 
 code https://stackblitz.com/edit/flex-layout-angular-material-zav7x4?file=app/test.component.html

Comment: @M4V3N: Also, try not to use `height` explicitly if you are using `flex-layout` because the main reason for using it, is to make UI responsive. Prefer `https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxFlex-API` . I hope now you can mark my answer as selected and upvote for my efforts :P

Comment: i see, thank you. But I dont think I can mark comments as selected answer. You need to update your original answer so I can mark it as solved.

Comment: @M4V3N : I answered your query in the answer itself. What you asked after that was a part of comment when u were adding other `components` with incorrect styling. It has nothing to do with the asked question. What I answered above still stands against your question. Rest, u decide as per your will. Cheers